Login with google and streamlit
I am doing a login with google oauth and streamlit, where at login time it works correctly along with the log out, but when I refresh the page it logs me out.
This is the google_auth.py
import asyncio
from typing import Optional
import jwt
import streamlit as st
from httpx_oauth.clients.google import GoogleOAuth2
from httpx_oauth.oauth2 import OAuth2Token

testing_mode = st.secrets.get("testing_mode", False)
client_id = st.secrets["client_id"]
client_secret = st.secrets["client_secret"]
redirect_url = (
    st.secrets["redirect_url_test"] if testing_mode else st.secrets["redirect_url"]
)
client = GoogleOAuth2(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)


def decode_user(token: str):
    decoded_data = jwt.decode(jwt=token, options={"verify_signature": False})
    return decoded_data

async def get_authorization_url(client: GoogleOAuth2, redirect_url: str) -> str:
    authorization_url = await client.get_authorization_url(
        redirect_url,
        scope=["email"],
        extras_params={"access_type": "offline"},
    )
    return authorization_url

def markdown_button(
    url: str, text: Optional[str] = None, color="#FD504D", sidebar: bool = True
):
    markdown = st.sidebar.markdown
    if sidebar:
            st.sidebar.title("Barra Lateral")
            st.sidebar.write("Este es un texto en la barra lateral.")
            markdown(
                f"""
            <a href="{url}" target="_blank">
                <div style="
                    display: inline-flex;
                    -webkit-box-align: center;
                    align-items: center;
                    -webkit-box-pack: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
                    border-radius: 0.25rem;
                    margin: 0px;
                    line-height: 1.6;
                    width: auto;
                    user-select: none;
                    background-color: {color};
                    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
                    text-decoration: none;
                    ">
                    {text}
                </div>
            </a>
            """,
                unsafe_allow_html=True,
            )
    else:
        st.markdown
    

async def get_access_token(
    client: GoogleOAuth2, redirect_url: str, code: str
) -> OAuth2Token:
    token = await client.get_access_token(code, redirect_url)
    return token


def get_access_token_from_query_params(
    client: GoogleOAuth2, redirect_url: str
) -> OAuth2Token:

    code = st.query_params["code"]

    token = asyncio.run(
        get_access_token(client=client, redirect_url=redirect_url, code=code)
    )
    # Clear query params
    st.query_params.clear()
    return token


def show_login_button(
    text: Optional[str] = "Login with Google", color="#FD504D", sidebar: bool = True
):
    authorization_url = asyncio.run(
        get_authorization_url(client=client, redirect_url=redirect_url)
    )
    markdown_button(authorization_url, text, color, sidebar)


def get_logged_in_user_email() -> Optional[str]:
    if "email" in st.session_state:
        return st.session_state.email

    try:
        token_from_params = get_access_token_from_query_params(client, redirect_url)
    except KeyError:
        return None

    user_info = decode_user(token=token_from_params["id_token"])

    st.session_state["email"] = user_info["email"]

    return user_info["email"]

def get_user_info() -> Optional[str]:
    if "email" in st.session_state:
        return st.session_state.email

    try:
        token_from_params = get_access_token_from_query_params(client, redirect_url)
    except KeyError:
        return None

    user_info = decode_user(token=token_from_params["id_token"])

    st.session_state["email"] = user_info["email"]

    return token_from_params

This is the main.py
import streamlit as st
import google_auth as ga

# Initialization of the session status and title container
if 'page_title' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.page_title = 'Login'
if 'page_name' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.page_name = 'Login'
if 'logged_in' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.logged_in = False

# Create an empty container for the title
title_placeholder = st.empty()

# Title update function
def update_title():
    title_placeholder.title(st.session_state.page_title)

# Show current title from session_state
update_title()

def go_to_page(page_name):
    # Update title in session_state
    st.session_state.page_title = page_name
    update_title()  # Update title in screen

def add_auth(
    login_button_text: str = "Login with Google",
    login_button_color: str = "#3383FF",
    login_sidebar: bool = True,
    page_name: str = 'Inicio'
):
    # User auth
    user_email = ga.get_logged_in_user_email()

    # If no email, show login button
    if not user_email:
        ga.show_login_button(
            text=login_button_text, color=login_button_color, sidebar=login_sidebar
        )
        st.stop()
    else:
        # If the user is logged in, store login state
        st.session_state.logged_in = True
        go_to_page(page_name)  # Switch to home page

        # Set email in session_state
        st.session_state.email = user_email

        # Show the user email
        st.write(f"User email: {user_email}")

    # Logout button
    if st.sidebar.button("Logout", type="primary"):
        # When logging out, clear session status
        if 'email' in st.session_state:
            del st.session_state.email
        st.session_state.logged_in = False
        st.session_state.page_title = 'Login'  # Set the title to 'Login'.
        go_to_page('Login')  # Change the visible title

        # Force application restart
        st.rerun()

# Execute the authentication function with the configured title
add_auth(page_name='Inicio')


I am trying to make use of cookies to stay in the session when I refresh, however, the options are not working.
What should I do?
